# Windows Authentication in IIS 8.5, Windows server 2012 .net 4.5

Tags: windows-authentication, iis-8, iis-8.5

We have been getting HTTP 500 and 401 access denied with IIS 8.5 Windows authentication ,Windows server 2012. It was a working thing before until they upgraded to .net 4.5
There were some posts where people had problems with IIS 8.5 and windows, but I am left still searching.  Can someone give me some hints on this issue we have been facing. 
We are using Windows Authentication with Active Directory,  disabled anonymous authentication.Also tried apppoolidentity, networkserviceaccount. It is a permissions issue which has been changed by Microsoft

Once the administrators connects to a web service every one can connect. 
If a person who is not a part of the administrators group tries to connect first, obviously it fails for them and  then no one else including the admin can connect. At this point only IIS reset and app pool reset a couple of times can help
We tried all sorts of web config changes here. Used Ntlm, negotiate and anonymous authentication.
This is fiddler log. It does not go past IIS authentication.

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><s:Body><s:Fault><faultcode xmlns:a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/net/2005/12/windowscommunicationfoundation/dispatcher">a:InternalServiceFault</faultcode><faultstring xml:lang="en-US">The type initializer for '&lt;Module&gt;' threw an exception.</faultstring><detail><ExceptionDetail xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.ServiceModel" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><HelpLink i:nil="true"/><InnerException><HelpLink i:nil="true"/><InnerException i:nil="true"/><Message>Access is denied</Message><StackTrace>   at System.Diagnostics.ProcessManager.OpenProcess(Int32 processId, Int32 access, Boolean throwIfExited)&#xD;
   at System.Diagnostics.NtProcessManager.GetModuleInfos(Int32 processId, Boolean firstModuleOnly)&#xD;
   at System.Diagnostics.ProcessManager.GetModuleInfos(Int32 processId)&#xD;
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.get_Modules()&#xD;
   at e5d1OZESgxkHKTAiuF.eqqrt5LE3cVaS2s6Kr.uXUty05WO0oTNxRkMa(Object )&#xD;
   at e5d1OZESgxkHKTAiuF.eqqrt5LE3cVaS2s6Kr.el9Dh8lMb()&#xD;
   at .cctor()</StackTrace><Type>System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception</Type></InnerException><Message>The type initializer for '&lt;Module&gt;' threw an exception.</Message><StackTrace>   at SyncInvokeCreateSessionUsingDomainAuthentication(Object , Object[] , Object[] )&#xD;
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SyncMethodInvoker.Invoke(Object instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]&amp; outputs)&#xD;
   at </StackTrace><Type>System.TypeInitializationException</Type></ExceptionDetail></detail></s:Fault></s:Body></s:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote something up for this:

- [How to enable Windows Authentication on a Windows Server 2012 IIS website using Powershell?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36554106/740575)

I'd suggest recreating the site and new application pool with the default authentication settings.  Ensure you have installed the `Web-Windows-Auth` prerequisite. and made the appropriate `Set-WebConfigurationProperty` changes.

You shouldn't have to make any changes to the AppPool or website file permissions.